# How do I install SIP makefile to use PyQt?

Tags: python, c++, windows, makefile

I want to install sip to use with PyQt.

1. I've unpacked the sip download
2. I ran Windows command prompt and changed dir to C:\Python\sip\
3. I ran the `configure.py` script, I did try the `python configure.py` first but because I unpacked the sip folder into C:\Python I couldn't get command line to recognise the python shell
4. This returned the makefile in command prompt, i couldn't then use make, it just gave me the error `'make' is not recognized`
5. I looked into it and thought i would solve this by using minGW
6. Now my command prompt shows:

   `C:\Python\sip>configure.py --platform win32-g++
   This is SIP 4.17 for Python 2.7.11 on win32.
   The SIP code generator will be installed in C:\Python27.
   The sip module will be installed in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages.
   The sip.h header file will be installed in C:\Python27\include.
   The default directory to install .sip files in is C:\Python27\sip.
   Creating siplib\sip.h...
   Creating siplib\siplib.c...
   Creating siplib\siplib.sbf...
   Creating sipconfig.py...
   Creating top level Makefile...
   Creating sip code generator Makefile...
   Creating sip module Makefile...`
7. I then run make and i get

   `C:\Python\sip>make
   'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
   operable program or batch file.`

I've searched through Stack and some are close to the answer but nothing has got me quite there yet.

I'm looking into downloading visual studio as I have been reading that your supposed to run the makefile from there on windows.

Is this correct or am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

So I've found the correct way to use make. I had to set my path to include mnGW and use: `mingw32-make` and `mingw32-make install`

I found this ironically on the python wiki!

https://wiki.python.org/moin/BuildPyQt4Windows